# Does curl_getinfo() work if there is a curl error?

Tags: php, curl

Are there any curl error number codes (i.e. `curl_errno($ch)`) which would prevent using `curl_getinfo` (i.e. `curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE)`)?

Comment: sure. if the url can't even be reached in the first place, by definition it'd be impossible to get an http code for the response, because you can't have a response without having done a request in the first place.

Comment: As far as I know, `curl_info` would still work after a curl error, and will contain all the info which the request can provide.

Comment: @MarcB  Didn't know whether it would return a 400 or 404, or whether `curl_getinfo()` would return an error if attempted.